# Most efficient way to compare list data

Tags: python, arrays, list, set, compare

I'm using python and trying to compare data between lists. List `A` will have data that looks like:

`A=['perspectiveA', 'perspectiveB', 'perspectiveC']`

And list `B` will have data that looks like:

`B=['listB.data.perspectiveA', 'listB.data.perspectiveB', 'listB.data.perspectiveC']`

I'm trying to make sure that the data gathered in list `A` is contained in the data gathered in list `B`. Is the only way to do this by using a nested for loop? I don't want to simply see if an item from `A` is in one of the items from `B`, but I need to make sure a 1:1 correlation. For instance, list B needs to contain one item that *contains* 'perspectiveA' but only one item.

Comment: Using lists is going to force you to be inefficient here.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, but my thought so far is I can create a new list out of the items in list B, but strip by '.' down to the last element and then compare both lists as sets to make sure they are identical. Just feel like that is a bit of a band-aid solution.

Answer (score 0):

Convert both lists to sets:

```
set('listB.data.' + x for x in A) == set(B)
# True
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not move the elements in one of your lists (List A, since it sounds like the data in that list is unique) into a dictionary, since searching through that data type is much faster, and you can retain your counters there as well:

```
listA = ['perspectiveA', 'perspectiveB', 'perspectiveC']
listB = ['listB.data.perspectiveA', 'listB.data.perspectiveB', 'listB.data.perspectiveC']
dictA = {a:0 for a in listA}

>>> dictA
{'perspectiveA': 0, 'perspectiveB': 0, 'perspectiveC': 0}

for b in listB:
    value = b.split(".")[2]
    if value in dictA:
        dictA[value] += 1
```

Any dictionary elements that have values other than 1 are either no-shows or duplicates.